# What is the difference between reject and discard

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-meaning

As far as I think
We reject something we recieve:

Eg: Transplant patients take powerful drugs so that their body will not reject the new kidney or heart.

We discard something we already have:

Eg: Hilary bundled up the clothes she had discarded

But still I'm skeptical about it

As the web dictionary says
Discard and reject are synonyms

Answer (score 1):

As verbs the difference between reject and discard is that reject is to refuse to accept while discard is to throw away, to reject.

**Reject:**

Verb (en-verb) - To refuse to accept.

Passage = One morning I had been driven to the precarious refuge afforded by the steps of the inn, after rejecting offers from the Celebrity to join him in a variety of amusements. But even here I was not free from interruption, for he was seated on a horse-block below me, playing with a fox terrier.
(basketball) To block a shot, especially if it sends the ball off the court.

Synonyms
* (refuse to accept) decline, refuse, turn down, repudiate, disown, abnegate, abjure, deny

Antonyms
* (refuse to accept) accept, take up

Noun
(en-noun)
Something that is rejected.
An unpopular person.

Synonyms
* (something that is rejected) castaway * (an unpopular person) outcast, castaway, alien)

**Discard:**

Verb (en-verb) to throw away, to reject.

A man discards the follies of boyhood.

(card games) To make a discard; to throw out a card.

To dismiss from employment, confidence, or favour; to discharge.

- Jonathan Swift
  They blame the favourites, and think it nothing extraordinary that the queen should resolve to discard them.
  Synonyms
- cast away * dismiss * dispose * eliminate * get rid of * throw away * See also
  Noun (en-noun)

Anything discarded.
A discarded playing card in a card game.

https://wikidiff.com/reject/discard

Comment: Reject equals to deny, right?

Comment: Yes, it can be used as deny.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms are just words  that **can be** used instead of other words.
Your understanding of the two words in the context provided is correct.

We 'reject' ideas, transplants, attitudes. It usually denotes a reaction of ejection.

We 'discard' items, rubbish, old habits, useless 'stuff'. A snake will discard it's old skin but this only takes place after the actual shedding process.

Discard = throw away

Reject = do not accept

You are not discarded from a job position, your application is rejected.

You do not reject faeces, you discard non-metabolized waste product.